# vector field of a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I have a problem to understand vector fields on manifolds. Theoretically I get it, but I cannot find a concrete example with numbers.

For example, I have the $S^2$ sphere and I take the classic polar parametriazation ($\theta$,$\phi$)$\to$ r($\theta$,$\phi$) in order to get the vector fields r$\theta$,r$\phi$.What are those vector fields?Are they a base of the tangent space?Obviously they are, but why?

Are they the same with the canonical base $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$?

Answer (score 1):

The basis of the tangent space is indeed $\frac\partial{\partial\theta},\frac\partial{\partial\phi}$. This is an abstracted form, which is also sometimes written as $\partial_\theta,\partial_\phi$.

We can associate the points on the sphere with the coordinates in the map $(\theta,\phi)$ and then *'read'* the basis vectors *'through the coordinate map'*. If we do, we get:
$$\frac\partial{\partial\theta}(\theta,\phi)=(1,0)\quad\text{and}\quad\frac\partial{\partial\phi}(\theta,\phi)=(0,1)$$
So we see that they span indeed a 2-dimensional tangent space. The differential map of the coordinate map transforms them to the unit vectors in its coordinate space.

For comparison, if we look at the embedding of $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$ with its canonical cartesian coordinate map $(x,y,z)$, we get:
$$\frac\partial{\partial\theta}(\cos\phi\sin\theta,\ \sin\phi\sin\theta,\ \cos\theta)=(\cos\phi\cos\theta,\ \cos\phi\cos\theta,\ -\sin\theta)$$
And if we *'read through the cartesian coordinate map'* $(x,y)$ of $S^2$, we get:
$$\frac\partial{\partial\theta}(\cos\phi\sin\theta,\ \sin\phi\sin\theta)=(\cos\phi\cos\theta,\ \cos\phi\cos\theta)$$
which is the representation of $\frac\partial{\partial\theta}$ in the cartesian coordinate map.

Comment: I am a bit confused now.Is that wright: r$\theta$:$R^2$ $\to$ $R^3$ as                     ($\theta$,$\phi$) $\to$ ($\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}$,$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$,$\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}$) and this is the same as e1?

Comment: @jane, yes, the resulting vector is the representation of $\mathbf e_1=\frac\partial{\partial\theta}$ in the embedding given by $f(\theta,\phi)=(x(\theta,\phi), y(\theta,\phi), z(\theta,\phi))$.